# WHMCS custom Domain register module

Tags: php, whmcs

I am trying to create custom domain registrar module for my whmcs platform. In registrars page my new registrar is active, getConfigArray function works correctly but when I accept user from my orders list for registering new domain whmcs does not read my registerdomain function written in my module. Nothing prints in modules logs neither error nor anything else.
Can anyone help?

```
function moduleName_RegisterDomain($params)
{
    $fields = array(
      'action'   => 'domain_create',
      'domain'   => $params["sld"] . '.' . $params["tld"],
      'username' => $params["Username"],
      'password' => $params["Password"],
    'owner'    => $params["firstname"] . ' ' . $params["lastname"],
    'period'   => $params["regperiod"],
    'street'   => $params["address1"],
    'city'     => $params["city"],
    'postcode' => str_replace(' ', '', $params["postcode"]),
    'country'  => $params["countrycode"],

    'adminname' => $params["adminfirstname"] . ' ' . $params["adminlastname"],

    'adminstreet'   => $params["adminaddress1"],
    'admincity'     => $params["admincity"],
    'adminpostcode' => str_replace(' ', '', $params["adminpostcode"]),
    'admincountry'  => $params["admincountry"],
    'adminemail'    => $params["adminemail"],
    'admintel'      => normalisePhone($params["adminphonenumber"]),
    'techname'      => $params["adminfirstname"] . ' ' . $params["adminlastname"],

    'techstreet'   => $params["adminaddress1"],
    'techcity'     => $params["admincity"],
    'techpostcode' => str_replace(' ', '', $params["adminpostcode"]),
    'techcountry'  => $params["admincountry"],
    'techemail'    => $params["adminemail"],
    'techtel'      => normalisePhone($params["adminphonenumber"]),

    'billname' => $params["adminfirstname"] . ' ' . $params["adminlastname"],

    'billstreet'   => $params["adminaddress1"],
    'billcity'     => $params["admincity"],
    'billpostcode' => str_replace(' ', '', $params["adminpostcode"]),
    'billcountry'  => $params["admincountry"],
    'billemail'    => $params["adminemail"],
    'billtel'      => normalisePhone($params["adminphonenumber"]),

    'ns1name' => $params["ns1"],

    'ns2name' => $params["ns2"],

    'ns3name' => $params["ns3"],

    'ns4name' => $params["ns4"],
);
$request = sendToclouds($fields, $params);
if (!$request['status']) {
    $values["error"] = $request['massage'];
} else {
    $values["massage"] = true;
}
return $values;
```

}

```
function sendToclouds($fields, $params)
{
  if ($params['TestMode']) {
    $fields['mode'] = 'test';
}

$curl = curl_init(); // we are using cURL library here
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $params["cloudsURL"]);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 90);
$out = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if ($out) {
    $str = strtolower($out);
    if (strpos($str, 'error') !== false) {
        return array('status' => false, 'massage' => $out);
    } else {
        return array('status' => true, 'massage' => $out);
    }

} else {
    return array('status' => false, 'massage' => 'Service unavailable');
}
```

}

Comment: can you please share register function of the module?

Comment: @wesamly  I have shared my register function. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The registrar function look fine.

- Did you assign the extension to the Registrar module, Setup > Products and Services > Domain Pricing under Auto Registration.
- After accepting the order, check domain details page and make sure that Registrar set to your module.
- If it is set correctly, or you set it manually, click Register under Registrar Commands, it will try to execute registration function.
- Make sure your registration function is called, by placing `error_log('registering domain...', 3, __DIR__.'/file.log');` in the first line in the function. if it is called it will write the string to file.log in the same directory.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I will check this cases thank you. Please be in touch I will let you know the result

Comment: manual clicking on register command worked thank you. but I want to accept from my orders list which need to be automatically call register function. That case does not work

Comment: Did you confirm first point? "Did you assign the extension to the Registrar module"

Comment: Hi @wesamly . Didn't help. Can you help with another way ?